# Proper notation regarding the constant of integration with respect to solving differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

From a textbook example/explainer, the differential equation:
$$2(y+3)dx - xydy=0$$
has the solutions:

$y=2\ln(x)+3\ln(y+3)+C$

or
$y=\ln(x^2(y+3)^3(C_1))$

where $C=\ln(C_1)$

Now I'm solving some of the practice problems and all the listed answers only has $C$
where clearly $C=\ln(C_1)$ was applied in making a more compact solution, implying that all the constant transformation was "condensed" into that $C$

What's the proper notation regarding this if I were asked for my workings? Should I also just "condense" into $C$? Or is my understanding of this wrong and this isn't even a notational question?

A sample problem listed was $(1-x)dy=y^2dx$ with the solution listed as $y\ln(C(1-x))=1$
but my workings show that it should be $y\ln(C_1(1-x))=1$.

Comment: The last example is just changing the name of the arbitrarily chosen variable $C$ vs $C_1$? There is nothing special about the name. You can pick anything you want (as long as it's unused of course)

Comment: @MikaelÖhman The variable $C$ was the listed answer directly next to the problem at the textbook. My workings on the other hand showed $C_1$ reflecting the transformation $C = \ln(C_1)$ after integration.

Comment: Yes because you chose to use call it that? You could have chosen to call the constant $D$ if you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a particular reason to do otherwise, always condense your solution by grouping all of the constants together in a "$+C$" term. After all, if $C_1$ is a constant, so is $\ln(C_1)$, $\sin(C_1)$, $\sqrt{C_1}$, $32C_1^{100}$, and so on.

Moreover, any antiderivative of a function will differ from another by a constant anyways, so there's generally no benefit to not condensing the constants together.